# "Current Statement" line during debugging has multiple background/foreground colors In Visual Studio causing hard to read text

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and during debugging, the current statement line has two sets of background/foreground colors which makes the whole line hard to read. The colors shown below is after I tried choosing colors which make both color sets have enough contrast to read but the contrast is not strong enough.

It seems there are two color actions happening at the same time causing the two color sets to occur, one dark on light and one light on dark. I disabled a few VS extensions thinking they are interfering and that didn't help.

The yellow background and corresponding forecolor is what's defined for "Current Statement" color setting. I went through all the colors searching for the other color set and I couldn't find it. Exported the settings and couldn't find those colors in the file. Ran VS in safe mode and the issue still exists.

Is there a way to get the whole current statement line to have just one background/foreground color set? or some workaround?

[image]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of this problem?

Comment: Sorry.. forgot to add it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you modified your Visual Studio 2015 editor color settings.
Please try resetting them back to default by choosing Tools > Options > Environment > General > and choose "Color Theme" = "Light" (or "Dark"):

[image]

This is how it looks under "Dark" theme for me, during debug and evaluate:

[image]

Comment: Yes the color theme is set to Dark and I want it to stay at Dark.  I should have a good color experience like the Light color theme experience, unless this is a bug in Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the color scheme? I have VS 2015 SP1 and I don't experience this problem. Maybe install SP1 ?

Comment: I have Update 1 installed. Flipping between Light and Dark didn't help. Are you saying you don't experience this in your Dark theme?

Comment: You're using a different dark color scheme which coincidentally makes your color sets have enough contrast. Yours also uses more than a single color set. Are you using the default dark color scheme?

Comment: Yes I am.... That's why I suggested you "reset" your color scheme back to the default "dark".